# How to generate Ms.Word file from HTML in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, doc

I have seen examples in PHP that HTML could be rendered in respected Doc Document. Somehow I did not find ways to do it in Python.

I am planning a Web app that would have an HTML editor(CKEditor etc). THen I can create Doc file out of it.

Comment: Try finding what libraries the PHP scripts are using, then see if there are Python bindings for those libraries. Otherwise, I guess you might be looking at some sort of hacky wrapper around the Open Office binaries.

Comment: @bsa - it's also possible the PHP script is just shipping HTML with the extension `.doc` - MS Office products go to sometimes ridiculous lengths to do the right thing when the file they are provided isn't what they were expecting.

Comment: @SeanVieira you say I create a HTML file and set extension as DOC? Did you try yourself?

Comment: @Volatil3 - nope, but I've seen the same sort of thing done with tab delimited text files and the `.xls` extension.